# How to scrape a list from Wikipedia?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am facing a similar problem to the question asked by [How can I scrape a list from wikipedia and transfer to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504317/how-can-i-scrape-a-list-from-wikipedia-and-transfer-to-a-dataframe). I want to create a dataframe from the list 'Modern wars with fewer than 25,000 deaths by death toll' in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_by_death_toll) with the column names 'Death toll', 'War', 'Date'.

The solution proposed in the other post does not work for me as the Wikipedia code is different and I can't seem to find a class name for the list.

I am using BeautifulSoup as follows:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_by_death_toll"

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

I have tried multiple things including searching

`soup.find_all('lu')` or `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mw-content-ltr"})[0].find_all("li")`
as well as

```
ul_elements = soup.find_all("ul")
for ul in ul_elements:
    # Find all <li> elements within the <ul> element
    li_elements = ul.find_all("li")
    for li in li_elements:
        # Print the text content of each <li> element
        print(li.get_text())
```

Nothing seems to work. The last option for instance prints out way more than alone my list, and I don't know how to limit the result just to my list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_by_death_toll"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


data = []
for li in soup.select_one(
    'h3:-soup-contains("Modern wars with fewer than 25,000 deaths by death toll") ~ ul'
).find_all("li"):
    if " – " in li.text:
        a, b = li.text.split(" – ", maxsplit=1)
    else:
        a, b = li.text.split(" ", maxsplit=1)

    if "[" in b:
        b = b.split("[")[0]

    link = None
    if li.a:
        link = li.a["href"]

    data.append((a, b, link))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Deathtoll", "Name", "Link"])
print(df.head(10))
```

Prints:

```
  Deathtoll                                       Name                                         Link
0    22,211   Croatian War of Independence (1991–1995)           /wiki/Croatian_War_of_Independence
1   22,000+      Dominican Restoration War (1863–1865)              /wiki/Dominican_Restoration_War
2   21,000+                         Six-Day War (1967)                            /wiki/Six-Day_War
3    20,068                     Reform War (1857–1860)                             /wiki/Reform_War
4   20,000+                     Yaqui Wars (1533–1929)                             /wiki/Yaqui_Wars
5   20,000+  War of the Quadruple Alliance (1718–1720)          /wiki/War_of_the_Quadruple_Alliance
6   20,000+                 Ragamuffin War (1835–1845)                         /wiki/Ragamuffin_War
7   20,000+              Italo-Turkish War (1911–1912)                      /wiki/Italo-Turkish_War
8    20,000              Anglo-Spanish War (1727–1729)  /wiki/Anglo-Spanish_War_(1727%E2%80%931729)
9   19,619+             Rhodesian Bush War (1964–1979)                     /wiki/Rhodesian_Bush_War
```